# How to expose a method to setup a member in a large class?

Tags: c#, class, methods, properties

I have a class, describing a user in the system:

```
class userInfo
{
    private SomeType1 p1;
    private SomeType2 p2;
    // ...
    private SomeTypek pk;
}
```

Setting a value to some `pi` involves a significant amount of code.
Up until now I defined a different method for each `pi` but the class grew, so I'd like to be able to define a method:

```
void SetPi(pi, SomeTypei value)
{
    //Set pi's value to value
}
```

Is this kind of thing possible in C#?

Comment: I think it is possible using Reflection.

Comment: How do you use the *p* fields?

Comment: @galenus They are used as some sort of a cache to a remote DB. Writing to them requires some logic which I'd like to hide in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not best idea to design you interaction with DB by that way. But if you want:

```
public class Class
{
    private string p1;
    private int p2;
    private decimal p3;

    public void SetPi<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        var field = this.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (field == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Field not found in Class.");

        field.SetValue(this, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   var c = new Class();    
   c.SetPi("p1", "AAA");
   c.SetPi("p2", 12);
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! Is there anyway to enforce that T is the correct type?

Comment: You will get exception at field.SetValue method if type is wrong anyway. You can add pre-check but it doesn't change the behavior only specify the reason of error.

Answer (score 0):

If they were all the same type, I'd suggest that you expose it as a list. Them being different types means that the only way you could do it in one method is to change to a more general type, like `object` or with generics, `T`. In doing this, you'll lose type safety and probably complicate the method.

You might want to change your fields into properties, give them descriptive names (assuming you actually have it like this: p1, p2, etc don't make sense, particularly if they're different types; if something like p1, p2 would make sense, that means it should be a list of things, named `p` or whatever `p` is short for), and internally call a method to handle the writing (the code is made a bit simpler by using [`CallerMemberName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx)).

```
public string UserName
{
    get
    {
        return _userName;
    }
    set
    {
        _userName = value;
        WriteToDB(value);
    }
}
// etc

private void WriteToDB(object value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    // propertyName will be "UserName" when called above
}

// use like
myUser.UserName = "Tommy";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will meet your requirements, i.e., is it crucial to use fields and do you have a single value for each type (in both cases the below is definitely not an answer), but here is something which does not involve reflection and is strongly typed:

```
class UserInfo
{
    private static class Cache<T> where T : class
    {
        public static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<UserInfo, T> ValuesByInstance =
            new ConditionalWeakTable<UserInfo, T>();
    }

    public void SetValue<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        Cache<T>.ValuesByInstance.Remove(this);
        Cache<T>.ValuesByInstance.Add(this, value);
    }

    public T GetValue<T>() where T : class
    {
        T value;
        Cache<T>.ValuesByInstance.TryGetValue(this, out value);

        return value;
    }
}
```